# whitespace out of html body

Tags: html, css

I have a very annoying html/css design-bug:

I want to have a footer with a height of `25px`, which always stays on the bottom of the site.

The site should always consume `100%` of the browser's screen, and must not display scrollbars.

**Here's a simplified version of the html, which causes the bug:**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">foo</div>
    <div id="tools">    
        <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
        <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

**The css:**

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body, html{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#content{
    background-color: #bbb;
    height: calc(100% - 25px);
}

#tools{
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#tools img{
    height: 100%;
}
```

The footer always uses `25px of height`, the content-div above consumes the rest.

However, I get an additional whitespace of 4px below the footer, which leads the vertical scrollbar to appear:

[image: screenshot]

This appears in all Browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera), so it must be my fault. When I remove the image-element, the space disappears.

What causes this problem and how can I avoid it?

Note that `overflow: hidden;` in the body-element is not an option.

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRvh5/3/)**

Comment: what is the purpose to use `position: absolute;` on `body` element?

Comment: @KheemaPandey I thought `position: absolute;` is needed in order to specify `top`, `left`,.. -attributes. But it seems I was wrong - removed it. thx

Comment: and what if you add `margin:0` and `padding:0` directly on body, html? no a good practice to use a `*` selector to removing `margin` and `padding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use the regular style of fixed footer on your `#tools` container:

```
position:fixed; 
bottom:0px;    
height:25px;
```

### [Update JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRvh5/5/)

**Markup**

```
<div id="content">foo</div>
<div id="tools">    
    <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
     <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
     <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
     <img src="img/save.png" alt="save file"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content{
    background-color: #bbb;
    height: 100%;
}

#tools{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:25px;
   width:100%;
   background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/FRvh5/4/)**

```
#tools img{
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was unexpected. However, in my actual program I have several images (siblings), and `display: block;` would force them to wrap.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and the question, there are now 2 images

Comment: you can use `vertical-align:bottom` instead of `display: block`. Refer the same DEMO link

Comment: This indeed solves the problem in my simplified version, but not in the actual program, so I can't accept it. However +1

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the image behaving like a character of text (and so leaving a space below it where the hanging part of a "y" or "g" would go), and is solved by using the `vertical-align` CSS property to indicate that no such space is needed. Almost any value of `vertical-align` will do;

```
#tools img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Cr9W/

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent tutorial to make the footers stay down properly, even if there is not much content: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page