# Remove whitespace at bottom of html/body height: 100% layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split a page into two equal areas, with each taking up 100% of the page height, and 50% of the page width.

However, this is resulting in an annoying whitespace at the bottom of the page, which also then leads to an annoying scroll bar on the whole page.

Normally, I'd use my browser's DOM inspector to find what is causing unwanted space, but it is of no use here, since the whitespace appears to be located outside of the html tag (?!).

The HTML is as follows (everything outside of body omitted for clarity)

```
<body><div id="box1"></div><div id="box2"></div></body>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; }

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

I've also created a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tb1gvhu/)**, which manages to replicate the problem.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992870/whitespace-out-of-html-body) that seems similar, but none of the answers there explain why this is occurring ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24993118/2045169) does offer an explanation for when img tags are present) and all of the fixes seem like hacks or workarounds.

Edit: In response to the comment (that seems to have disappeared), the problem is replicated in the Fiddle in Firefox 49.02 and Edge 38.14393.0.0 on Windows 10. It also occurs in Chrome 54.0.2840.71, but it is less noticeable (and the scroll bar doesn't seem to move if I have the window maximised).

Comment: So now you want to know or want the reason?? Bdw  you can use overflow:hidden to remove that scroll bar too. Overflow:hidden will remove extra space which is causing scroll bar.

Comment: @Leothelion - yes - what is causing the whitespace?

Comment: It's the CSS block `div {display: inline-block;}` - read into what inline-block means. Here's an updated fiddle with no whitespace - https://jsfiddle.net/ez4wm20c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure some people will add to this but here's my understanding...

You have `div {display: inline-block;}`. Inline blocks are kind of like a block but treated as text, so line height matters. If you update the first line of your CSS to...

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; line-height: 0;}
```

...the whitespace will go away. Play around with line-height in your fiddle to change the amount of white space you have. Values 14px and up started adding whitespace for me.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be it. I'm thinking a [flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) eliminates the need for all these hacks. I've updated the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m4a6d4gh/) to demonstrate this design with a flex layout.

Comment: Ah nice, `flex` is  a new one to me but seems to suit your needs. I'm mostly a PHP dev now but your question caught my eye! Have fun, and thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: YOU SAVED MY DAY!

Answer (score 2):

Just Add `overflow:hidden` in body tag css.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid red; }

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#box1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#box2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body><div id="box1"></div><div id="box2"></div></body>
```

Comment: This will also remove _wanted_ scrollbars.

Comment: @sachin i already mention in this thing in my comment and asking what you need as op know how to solve but asking the reason. Please read question first then try to post as answer so it will make SO site spam free. Thank you

Comment: In that case. You have to hide scrollbar ::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
} and use overflow:auto;

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya again m saying, op KNOWS how to solve but he is asking the reason. Now got my point??

Comment: Ok...@ leo the lion

Comment: This certainly will work, but as mentioned, will remove wanted scrollbars if there is any overflow. Surely there is a way to specify that the document should have a fixed height of *exactly* 100% - no more, no less.